Given array of objects sort by one of the object fields
Given that we have an array of articles where each article has a title , description and date . so we have a list of articles that are displayed . Now we have two buttons sort by title and sort by date which should sort the articles when the corresponding button is clicked.
How to implement this functionality ?
In my view I would store the articles array in a state variable and upon clicking the button
I will sort the articles either by title or by date and map through each article to display its content .
Any suggestions or better way to implement this functionality ?
Don't write the react code just give the pseudo code
Thanks you

Seems you have a working solution ... What's wrong with it?

Your proposed solution works fine, title can just sort alphabetically, for date you can probably just convert to UNIX timestamp and use a basic sort. Only thing is remember that if you overwrite the state variable with new sorted array, you'll lose the original order. So if you want to preserve original article order, store that in a ref as well, so you always have access to the articles in original, unsorted order

Take a few considerations into account to ensure that not all items are rendered again when sorting the list.
Render only the visible portion of the list instead of rendering all items. (Tools like React Window or React Virtualized can help)
Cache the sorted array using useMemo or a similar approach to avoid re-sorting every time the list or the component re-renders.
Ensure each list item has a unique key property that doesn’t change between re-renders. This helps React efficiently diff and update the DOM.

@kaveh absolutely right usememo to memorise the sorted result
